# Using the Data-uri-to-img-url service with jquery jsonp not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to use this to get image URL's http://aminariana.github.io/data-uri-to-img-url/ for sharing on facebook.

I just can't work out how to make the post request using jquery:

*# Make a POST request with param 'image[data_uri]' set to the above DataURI input.
  # This could be from an HTML form with a textarea, or programmatically using an AJAX POST request.*

I have setup a JS Fiddle that creates an image in canvas, converts the image to the datauri http://jsfiddle.net/7asutg7c/ it's just the last part of using jsonp in jquery to send the parameter and get the URL back that I am completely lost on.

```
    var url = 'http://data-uri-to-img-url.herokuapp.com/images.json';.
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: url,
       async: false,
       // data: dataURL,
       contentType: "application/json",
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       success: function(json) {
       console.log(json.url);
     },
      error: function(e) {
      console.log(e.message);
     }
    });
```

My initial thought was to set data to the dataURI but I get "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 414 (Request-URI Too Large)" ... so I am a little stuck about how I should be sending that dataURI.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a JavaScript object like this,

```
var myData = {
  image: {
    data_uri: your_data_uri_here
  }
};
```

and then pass that as value of the `data` parameter of the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting 414 (Request-URI Too Large) when I try it this way.

Comment: How big is the image you are trying to upload? Maybe there is a size limit, on the amount of upload data the service will accept?

Comment: Did you found solution to this? I believe heroku app is disabled for some reason. Any other way?